# uninitialized constant AWS::S3::NoSuchBucket

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using Rails 3 with the following code...

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :version => ">= 0.6.2", :lib => "aws/s3"
config.gem 'right_aws', :version => '2.0.0'
```

model.rb

```
has_attached_file :video, 
                      :storage => :s3,
                      :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
                      :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

                    # Paperclip Validations
                    validates_attachment_presence :video
                    validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ['application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/flv', 'video/x-flv']
```

s3.yml

```
development:
  bucket_name: tekbookvideo
  access_key_id: xxxx
  secret_access_key: yyyy
production:
  bucket_name: tekbookvideo
  access_key_id: xxxx
  secret_access_key: yyyy
```

And am getting the uninitialized constant AWS::S3::NoSuchBucket error...

I do not know what to do anymore...

Comment: 1) accept answers please, you have an acceptance rating of 0% right now 2) Rails 3 doesn't have config.gem anymore, are you sure you're using Rails 3? 3) Only use the `right_aws` as it does the same thing as the `aws-s3` gem, but is more recent.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem and experienced a very large headache over it. My eventual solution was to log in to amazon and create a new bucket. Then I set the name of the bucket in the model as a parameter like so...

```
has_attached_file :video,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'bucketname',
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in the current version of Paperclip. See:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/issue/363

Answer (score 1):

I heard people had this issue because there were using european bucket which is not support by aws3

Answer (score 1):

Posted this on a similar thread, but here it is again:

I was just having this very same issue. Then I read something about Paperclip creating buckets where they don't exist. I appended a 1 to the end of my already created bucket name, and all of a sudden it worked. I think it might have something to do with the other end. Try setting the bucket name to something other than the one you've probably already created... Highly counter intuitive...

Answer (score 1):

I created a european bucket first that didn't work. Recreating the bucket again in the standard US location did the trick for me. (Thx Boris).