# AWS::S3::CurrentBucketNotSpecified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

AWS::S3::CurrentBucketNotSpecified

No bucket name can be inferred from your current connection's address (`s3.amazonaws.com')

Has anyone seen this before? The app with Rails 3 + paperclip + s3 was working great, then I upgraded to RVM and this happened.

**/config/S3.yml**

```
common: &common
    access_key_id: 123123123123123123
    secret_access_key: asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd

development:
    <<: *common
    bucket: xxxx_dev

test:
    <<: *common
    bucket: xxxx_test

production:
    <<: *common
    bucket: xxxx_prod
```

In the model:

```
 # Paperclip for User.photo
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => "70x70>"
    },
    :path => "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'),
    :s3_protocol => 'https',
    :use_timestamp => false,
    :default_style => :thumb,
    :default_url => '/images/profile_default_70x70.png'
```

Any suggestions or ideas on the issue or how to debug? Thanks

UPDATE, I'm allowing for photos to be uploaded with a url as follows:

```
  before_validation :download_remote_image, :if => :photo_url_provided?

  # Used to handle paperclip via an image URL
  def photo_url_provided?
    !self.photo_url.blank?
  end

  # Used to handle paperclip via an image URL
  def download_remote_image
    self.photo = do_download_remote_image
  end

  # Used to handle paperclip via an image URL
  def do_download_remote_image
    io = open(URI.parse(photo_url))
    def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
    io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
  rescue # catch url errors with validations instead of exceptions (Errno::ENOENT, OpenURI::HTTPError, etc...)
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489542/uninitialized-constant-awss3nosuchbucket

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access a YML Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699753/how-to-access-a-yml-value)

Answer (score 1):

add

```
:s3_bucket => "xyz"
```

to your paperclip attributes.

I'd recommend using nifty:configuration for configuration data in different environments:

Comment: Thanks but I just added "    :s3_bucket => "xxxx_dev" manually and it didn't work. same error.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with photo_url, question updated with code.

Comment: I still get this in console when I try to save an image with a url:  ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > @user.save
AWS::S3::CurrentBucketNotSpecified: No bucket name can be inferred from your current connection's address (`s3.amazonaws.com')
 from /Users/bhellman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:107:in `current_bucket'
 from /Users/bhellman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:179:in `bucket_name'

Comment: look the answer above me, it might be :bucket not :s3_bucket, have to admit i switched to carrierwave

Answer (score 0):

I have `:bucket => 'bucket_name'` in my has_attached_file configuration hash.